# js promise which is not closed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, q, angular-promise

I have the following code and in the code when I enter **inside the if statement** `(if (that.cont) )` I get an error of a un-finished promise chain, what can be the reason for this and how should I avoid it?

```
run: function() {

    var oDef = Q.defer();
    var Obj = Q(sWUrl);
    if (that.cont) {
        Obj = that.cont.get(that.cont.transl).then(function(mSet) {
            debugger;
            if (mSet) {
                var lang = mSet.supportedLang;
                var dft = mSet.defaultLang;
                if (!dft) {
                    if (lang) {
                        dft = lang.split(",")[1];
                    } else {
                        dft = "en";
                    }
                }
                return Q(sWUrl + "&lang=" + window.encodeURIComponent(lang));
            } else {
                return Q(sWUrl);
            }
        }, function() {
            return Q(sWUrl);
        }).then(function(sUri) {
            return that.cont.se.pre.get("Pre").then(function(oPreSet) {
                return sUri + "&device=" + window.encodeURIComponent(oPreSet.dte);
            }).fail(function(error) {
                return sUri;
            });
        });
    }
    return Obj.then(function(sUri) {
        oWin.window.location.href = sUri;
        return oWin.oDef.promise;
    });
},
```

Comment: the `return` lies outside the `if` and the very last bracket doesn't close anything in this code - there is a bracket in excess somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Vld - Where is the bracket can you please show me after which statement ? Btw the last one is since this code is part of a big method...

Comment: I've submitted an edit with the code properly formatted - it makes it clear to see what doesn't belong - it's the very last closing curly bracket at the bottom of the code block.

Comment: @Vld-Thanks this brackets is part of a method ,i've updated my post with the method name which this brackets is belong too...is it ok now ?

Comment: Can you add two functions to `then`? Because you have two - one where the debugger is attached, and one after it which returns the same as the `else ` from the previous function - is that valid?

Comment: @Vld - did you mean that the second is return Obj.then(function(sUri) { ? if yes I think that this is valid...

Comment: Where are you getting an error of an unfinished promise chain? In the console? Is it pointing to any particular line?

Comment: @JLRishe-just when it enter to the debugger line (at the begining)line after the Obj = that.cont.get ....

Comment: If you remove the `debugger` line, do you still get an error? What is the actual error?

Comment: Also, side note: your `dft` variable is completely unused. Did you make a mistake there?

Comment: Which promise library are you using? `Q`, `$q`, or really both?

Comment: @Bergi- the Q libarary,any suggestion or tip how to proceed with this bug...,Thanks!

Comment: @Roamer-1888 In Q, `fail` is an alias for `catch`, so yes, it does filter if in fact the promise OP is dealing with is a Q promise.

Comment: @JLRishe, I think you're right. I've been dong too much jQuery recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where that error would be coming from, but one thing is for sure - whatever you return from `run` is never going to resolve, because you never resolve `oDef` (and you are using the "deferred antipattern").

You also seem to be mistakenly under the assumption that you *have* to return a promise from your handlers (although you are forgetting to do this in one place), but this is not true. You can just return ordinary values if there's nothing to await.

Give this a try:

```
run: function() {
    var p;
    if (that.cont) {
        p = that.cont.get(that.cont.transl).then(function(mSet) {
            if (mSet) {
                var lang = mSet.supportedLang;
                var dft = mSet.defaultLang;
                if (!dft) {
                    if (lang) {
                        dft = lang.split(",")[1];
                    } else {
                        dft = "en";
                    }
                }
                return sWUrl + "&lang=" + window.encodeURIComponent(lang);
            } else {
                return sWUrl;
            }
        }, function() {
            return sWUrl;
        }).then(function(sUri) {
            return that.cont.se.pre.get("Pre").then(function(oPreSet) {
                return sUri + "&device=" + window.encodeURIComponent(oPreSet.dte);
            }).fail(function(error) {
                return sUri;
            });
        });
    } else {
        p = Q(sWUrl);
    }

    return p.then(function(sUri) {
        oWin.window.location.href = sUri;
    });
},
```

Comment: @JhonDree Can you answer my questions?

Comment: I removed the if(mSet) completely and the problem is still there...any other suggestion ?

Comment: @JhonDree Can you answer my other question?

Comment: @JhonDree Please look at the comments section of your question and read my last two comments. There are two questions that you have not answered and one that I'm not sure whether you've answered or not.

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to answer since this is not my code :( and I need to fix this bug...any suggestion or some tip from your experience how should I proceed ?Thanks in advance!voted up for your help :)

Comment: @JhonDree Neither of these questions requires any understanding of the code. ___Why won't you answer them???___: _"If you remove the debugger line, do you still get an error? What is the actual error?"_ I cannot help you if you can't answer straightforward troubleshooting questions like these.

Comment: Yes (if I remove the debugger )The error is still exist I see that in the console.the error is "Unfinished promise chain in method run"

Comment: @JhonDree Well, the AngularJS and Q codebases don't seem to have the word "unfinished" anywhere in them, so the error doesn't seem to be coming from either of those. What is `that.cont`?

Comment: This is a service which do some general functionality,do you think that this can have the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74623/discussion-between-jhon-dree-and-jlrishe).